# prestodb Cannot connect to discovery server for refresh

Tags: presto

I am trying to Deploy the presto on single node . when running Presto coordinator server with discovery server embedded , i got following errors:

```
ERROR   Discovery-0 io.airlift.discovery.client.CachingServiceSelector  Cannot connect to discovery server for refresh (hive-metastore/general): Lookup of hive-metastore failed with status code 404
ERROR   Announcer-0 io.airlift.discovery.client.Announcer   Cannot connect to discovery server for announce: Announcement failed with status code 404: 
ERROR   Discovery-0 io.airlift.discovery.client.CachingServiceSelector  Cannot connect to discovery server for refresh (collector/general): Lookup of collector failed for http://172.16.2.111:8080/v1/service/collector/general
```

My node.id was produced by 'uuidgen'

my config.properties::

```
coordinator=true
datasources=jmx,hive
http-server.http.port=8080
presto-metastore.db.type=h2
presto-metastore.db.filename=/data/presto/coordinator/meta_db/MetaStore
task.max-memory=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=ture
discovery.uri=http://172.16.2.111:8080
```

node.properties:

```
node.environment=production
node.id=1dfa7386-36e8-44b1-bfe7-6955882eec5e
node.data-dir=/var/presto/coordinator
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error message occurs because the service selectors and announcer start trying to connect while the server is still starting. You should see *"succeeded for refresh"* and *"succeeded for announce"* shortly after in the logs which shows that it's working. We will fix the log message eventually but it's purely a cosmetic issue.

Comment: thanks for your help. but ,I didn't find any message contain "succeeded for refresh" and "succeeded for announce" .  <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /v1/announcement/1dfa7386-36e8-44b1-bfe7-6955882eec5e. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>

Comment: I can confirm the answer above - it fails once and then it retries and connects. However I ran across this post because I thought the error mentioned in the original post was why my Presto setup was not working with my Cassandra installation. What I determined in my scenario was that when following the steps from https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/cassandra.html you also need to define the "cassandra.username=cassandra <newline here> cassandra.password=cassandra" user/password in the cassandra.properties file that way Presto can login to the Cassandra cluster.